My tuna was left outside is it OK to eat?
I ordered several small boxes of bumblebee tuna salad and crackers.
The tuna salad is in a small can, boxed and Wrapped in cellophane. They mail person dropped them off in the middle of my driveway in the blazing sun for several hours. Is the tuna salad safe to eat inside a can, a small box,cellophane and a much larger box after being left directly in the sun??

The key question is: What kind of product are we talking about. I assume it’s the canned convenience product kind. That‘s perfectly safe while unopened, see the duplicate question.
